# SQL service accounts keep getting Locked out

Tags: sql, service-account

SQL service accounts keep getting locked out in AD. 
I have to unlock them everytime.

What could be the probable cause and a solution?

Comment: Can you got to that server and check into event log to see why this is happening

Comment: Is it SQL account or Windows Account for SQL Service? is it bring down the sql server?

Comment: How often is this happening?  If it happens at the same time every day, then a script or console app could be running using the wrong credentials for the service account and using those credentials incorrectly enough to lock the account.

Comment: Eventlog only tells me it's a logon failure. I've updated the password both in services, and sql config manager just to be certain. @WaqasSarwarMCSE they are not sql accounts, but windows account. and yes it does bring the server down unless I unlocked the service acct and restart the services.

Comment: @JamesGrizzle it happens almost everytime. But I can't figure out what app or script is using wrong credentials. Thank you.

Comment: anybody else is using the SQL service account, Check IIS or Service on the server and look if anything running under that service account

Answer (score 2):

You can do troubleshooting by looking in Windows eventviewer. There is a category "Security". Please look for the Keywords `Audit Failure`.

You might also use the tool [Lockout Status](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15201) to get more information how often a bad password is provided and when locking occurs.

Comment: Thank you, Now I can see the Lockout Status but still can't figure out why it keeps locking or which app is using a wrong credential.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a service account with wrong password somewhere. Its obviously trying more than three times and getting locked out.

You need to find out where that service account is being used and change its password as it could be using an old password. An example would be me creating some custom code and using the SQL service account that has hard coded username and password in the SQL string.